# How to check Win32 CreateProcess() failed reason using ProcMon. exclude GetLastError()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, createprocess, win32-process

I am having an issue with checking **CreateProcess()** failure reason, there was a code in production which doesn't log GetLastError() when CreateProcess() failed so i am running ProcMon to check the reason but unable to find the reason (Will procMon log the failure reason something like "C:\dummy.exe path not found or permission denied" ?).

Is there a way (tools ?) to check why CreateProcess() is failing without considering GetLastError() ?

I can't debug customer environment (no access to me) but I can change the code & provide new build & it takes long time due to process. i am currently **looking for quick options available**. Below is the sample code not exact production code.

```
int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO info = { sizeof(info) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;

    TCHAR dymmypath[_MAX_PATH] = _T("C:\\dummy.exe");
    static TCHAR TempPathString[_MAX_PATH];

    STARTUPINFO         si = { sizeof(si) };        //default set up
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;                     //data structure for CreateProcess

    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWMINIMIZED;

    if (!CreateProcess(dymmypath, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, TempPathString, &si, &pi))
    {
        printf("Failed");
    }
    else {
        printf("Success");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just attach a debugger?

Comment: @tenfour its in production with release build.

Comment: Release builds can still be debugged. Set a breakpoint on `kernel32!CreateProcessW`, step out, and see the error code.

Comment: @NDestiny - and so what ? in what problem use debugger ?

Comment: _"Is there a way (tools ?) to check why CreateProcess() is failing without considering GetLastError() ?"_ but __why?__. It's __your__ code, just add `GetLastError()` and fix the bug as suggested in tenfour's answer below.

Comment: _"Is there a way (tools ?) to check...."_: yes, it's called debugger.

Comment: edited my question for better understanding the situation

Comment: @NDestiny as already mentioned : `TempPathString` is uninitialized, it's a bug. You need to fix that. If a build it takes long time, you need to cope with that.

Comment: @Jabberwocky TempPathString initialized. because it static - all bytes 0 here

Comment: @RbMm `""` is not a valid path

Comment: @tenfour - yes, not valid. and call with exactly this code must **always** fail with *The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.* error. but i say only that `TempPathString` is zero initialized by fact. not say that this correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i am running ProcMon to check the reason but unable to find the reason (Will procMon log the failure reason something like "C:\dummy.exe path not found or permission denied" ?).

Only if the request reaches the filesystem, ie to look for the EXE file, which in your case it sounds like it is not doing that, likely because `CreateProcess()` is failing to validate your input parameters before it reaches into the filesystem.

> Is there a way (tools ?) to check why CreateProcess() is failing without considering GetLastError() ?

As others said, you could try attaching a debugger to your running app, and put a breakpoint in the `CreateProcess` function itself.

Another option is to use a tool like [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor), which will show you the actual API calls your program makes, what their parameter values are, reported error codes, etc.

> I can't debug customer environment (no access to me) but I can change the code & provide new build

Then that is what you *should* do.  Fix your code to do proper logging of error codes, don't ignore them anymore.

> it takes long time due to process.

Well, that is your own fault for not optimizing your build process better, or breaking up your app into more manageable pieces, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just at first glance, I see `TempPathString` is initialized to `""`, which is not a valid path. So while you're fixing that issue, that's your chance to add proper error handling.

The tool you're looking for is a debugger. You should attach the debugger of your choice, set a breakpoint on the return of `CreateProcess`, and check the error there.

Besides debugging and error handling (logging etc), you'll have to just get creative. Compare a working environment against production for example.

Comment: debugger, is is WinDbg or Visual studio debugger ?

Comment: @NDestiny either would work. WinDbg would be lighter-weight if you want to avoid installing Visual Studio on a production system. But it sounds like you have the ability to just change the code, so an option is to just build in enough error handling you don't need a debugger if that's a hassle.

Comment: `TempPathString` is initialized with 0 because it static. of course if this code at all relevant

Comment: as i said... code change will take long time to deliver again so looking for quick options & tools.. and ofcourse VS debuger is out of scope in production env for me.

Comment: If you cannot debug, and cannot change the code, then you're asking the impossible. If it's working in some other environment though at least you have a starting point to do the last resort: random guess-and-test. Next you'll tell us you don't have access to repro :D

Comment: @tenfour Debug means only debugging with VS debugger ?

Comment: i think my question is clear enough. can do whatever you suggested but looking for other quick options i mentioned always.

Comment: "then you're asking the impossible" - it is saying no other way

Comment: @NDestiny Have a look at [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) or other similar tool